# Syncfusion PDF parser code returning null in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code, parsing, pdf

I'm trying to parse and read the text from a PDF so I installed the Syncfusion library and used their code to load an existing PDF and extract the text from the first page however my Stream value is empty. Here is their website for reference: https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/8063/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-c-vb-net

My code:

```vb
Dim assembly As Assembly = GetType(FrmChrisBHSIInvoices).GetTypeInfo().Assembly

Dim fileStream As Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Child Care Solutions, LLC dba American Child_ISA-154243_02012024_06282023.pdf")

Dim loadedDocument As PdfLoadedDocument = New PdfLoadedDocument(fileStream)

Dim page As PdfPageBase = loadedDocument.Pages(0)

Dim extractedTexts As String = page.ExtractText(True)

loadedDocument.Close(True)
```

The fileStream value is coming up as null.

Comment: fileStream is null because either the resource name is incorrect (you might have to add the namespaces in front of the resource name) or your PDF file is not embedded as a resource in the application.